# Wordpress remove menus users.php leave only Profile

Tags: wordpress

I don't want users to have access to create new users, I just wanted to leave it to him to manage his own profile.

[image: image1]

The ideal was to leave only Profile.

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

you suppose to change user role to subscriber only and also you can user remove_cap wordpress function to remove capabilities from user.
below link my help you to resolve issue
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/remove_cap/